# Upon their visit or on their visit

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference, time

> In the report, the police have said the menu was neither displayed nor shared with the police by the canteen Staff upon  their visit

1-upon
2-on

I read this sentence  from a Indian news paper "the Hindu" and I am confused whether to use on or upon, in sentence  they used "upon"  as shown  above in sentence.

Comment: You need to specify if this happened when they arrived, or just sometime during their visit.

Answer (score 6):

The subtle difference is that **upon** denotes *moment in time* whereas **on** denotes both *moment in time* and *during*.

We can use "on" to mean "at a moment in time"

**On our arrival..**.  (the moment of our arrival)

or "during"

**On our journey...**

Locative uses aside, we use "upon"  nowadays mainly to refer to moments in time

> upon our *arrival*...
>
> we *set out* upon our journey
>
> upon seeing it for the first time...
>
> upon being informed that

not to duration:

<sup>archaism</sup> We met him while we were upon our journey.

Comment: I tend to agree with your assessment, but I'm not quite sure if using *upon* with a durative activity is really archaism. Personally, I think it's just more formal or maybe literary.

Comment: **Upon our journey** would be a rarity nowadays, even in a literary context, unless the author were deliberately seeking to evoke an earlier style. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+upon+our+journey&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20upon%20our%20journey%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

"Upon" is less used now but remains common in formal writing. "On" is deemed an acceptable substitution nowadays. They are interchangeable in cases like that. In some special cases only "upon" may be used. "Once upon a time..." and "Breakfast-time is upon us" are examples. These are special , less common, or more formal cases that emphasise the connection "upon" has with time and place in contrast to "on" being simply proximity.

Answer (score 2):

But you look up the prepositions on and upon in McMillan, Oxford, Longman, Cambridge, or The Free Dictionary, you will know that these prepositions can be used interchangeably in many cases. See McMillan for details. One of these cases is when one thing happens immediately after another. Look at the following sentences:

Please report to the reception desk on/upon your arrival.

Upon/On arriving home I discovered that he had gone.

She was joyful upon/on seeing her child.

Similarly, you can say 'on/upon their visit' in the sentence presented by the OP, without any difference in meaning.  However. the use of 'upon' is much more formal than 'on'.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upon

Comment: "dead on arrival (DOA)" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> In the report, the police have said the menu was neither displayed nor shared with the police by the canteen Staff **during** their visit.

In your example I would use *during*, since the "display or sharing" could have occurred anytime during their "visit". *Upon* would be better if you were referring to their arrival (upon being a moment in time).

I would not use "on" here, but it is not specifically wrong.